# Post form data with $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

Following code post form data as json and not key value pair.

*service*

```
            $resource(apiPath, {
                Id: '@Id',
                apt_id: user_info.apt_id,
                mauth_token: user_info.mauth_token,
                mauth_account_id: user_info.mauth_acnt_id,
                rest: 1,
            }, {
                save:{
                    method:'POST',
                    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                }
            });
```

*controller*

```
.controller('BroadcastSmsSendCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $ionicActionSheet, $state, $timeout, $location, BroadcastSmsSvcs, GetUserCountHttpSvcs) {
            $scope.entry = new BroadcastSmsSvcs();

            $scope.doSubmit = function() {
                BroadcastSmsSvcs.save({}, $scope.entry);
            };
        });
```

[image: Form data]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following in your `.config()` function

```
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.unshift(function (data, headersGetter) {
     var key, result = [], response;
     if(typeof data == "string") { //$http support
            response = data;
     } else {
            for (key in data) {
                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    result.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(data[key]));
                }
            }
            response = result.join("&");
        }
        return response;
});
```

Comment: I tried to modify this to work with a nested object and failed. I am trying to make it work for this obj:

    `var toTransform = {
        data: {
          show_notifications: {
            ratings: false,
            comments: false,
            subscribe: showSubscribe
          }
        }
      };`

Any chance I could get some help with that please?

Answer (score 12):

AngularJs provides a service which transforms to jQuery like serialization object.

Instead of json serialization: `{"id": 1, "name": "whatever"}`

It becomes: `id=1&name=whatever`

So simply you can do:

```
save:{
    method: "POST",
    headers : {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, 
    transformRequest: function(data) {
        return $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data);
    }
}
```

**Note**: In your service you have to inject the `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` service

Answer (score 3):

try adding this to your $resource object

```
headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
transformRequest : function(obj){
      var str = [];
      for(var p in obj)
        str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
      return str.join("&");
    }
  }
```